# Plugin can not display in my custom theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I have made my first theme. :) But I have a problem: plugins such as getsocial or dynamicwp-contact-form can not display in my custom theme. I tried using them in the twentyeleven theme, and they don't have that problem there.

I think there is a problem with my theme but I don't know where..

Answer (score 3):

Have you placed `<?php wp_head(); ?>` before the `</head>` tag and
`<?php wp_footer(); ?>` before the `</body>` tag?

Comment: yeahh. Thank you very much jessica. you fixing my problem. i just using <?php wp_footer(); ?>. I'm not using <?php wp_head(); ?> because make my css be broken. Any problem if I not using <?php wp_head(); ?> in next day???

Comment: @JuanLie lots of plugins use `wp_head` to add their CSS and JS to your theme. You might have a problem later if you add a new plugin that needs to use `wp_head`. It's better to make your CSS work with the plugin's CSS.

Answer (score 3):

For a theme to work, it must include all of the required functions for WordPress to hook to. `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` are two of these. You should really read the entire [Theme Development codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), but in particular, the ["Template File Checklist"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_File_Checklist) section may help you resolve a lot of issues.

In regards to your CSS problems, make sure you are using `wp_enqueue_style` to load your stylesheet (using `wp_head()` in fact).